# Django is not serving staticfiles

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I would like to use django staticfiles, but unfortunately I can't get it to serve to images locally.

This is what I have done so far:

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'content.apps.ContentConfig',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

When I do a print(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')) I see the correct local path.

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
import content.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', content.views.index, name='index'),
    path('/about', content.views.about, name='about'),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

templates:

```
{% load static %}
...
{% static "css/master.css" %}
```

resolves to

```
/static/css/master.css
```

[EDIT]
URL PATTERN looks like this

```
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL      
patterns, in this order:
admin/
[name='index']
/about [name='about']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
```

Opening a file directly ends up to a 404-django-page.

After that, I ran ./manage.py collectstatic successfully.

I am using the Django Dev server e.g. ./manage.py runserver...

I am maybe missing something, just need an additional pair of eyes. Thanks.

Comment: have you ran the `python manage.py collectstatic` command?

Comment: indeed... collected a lot of files - as it should.

Comment: It's django server? or web-server (`nginx`, `apache` etc)?

Comment: Local development using django Server

Comment: which version of Django?

Comment: Running Django 3.2

Comment: You can open your static file in url `localhost:8000/static/css/master.css`? alse can you show renderd html?

Comment: `{% static "css/master.css" %}` - just like that, directly to html or there is a `<link rel="stylesheet" ...` around it?

Comment: localhost:8000/static/css/master.css is showing a 404 = .'css/master.css' could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

and replacing it with

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),)
```

Comment: Thanks man. This solved my issue importing js libraries beyond django vanilla files. Before this, I was creating an entry with prefix in STATICFILES_DIRS, but that didn't work in production environment (with static files served via NGIX).